# getting "invalid integer syntax" for a varchar argument

Tags: postgresql

The function called has no integer arguments:

```sql
                                                              List of functions
 Schema |    Name     | Result data type |                                     Argument data types                                     | Type
--------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------
 web    | create_user | users            | user_email character varying, password_hashed character varying, language character varying | func
(1 row)

psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint.sql:2909: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "aaabbbccc"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at assignment
2021-03-06 00:01:23.451 UTC [46] ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "aaabbbccc"
2021-03-06 00:01:23.451 UTC [46] CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at assignment
2021-03-06 00:01:23.451 UTC [46] STATEMENT:  DO $$ -- nocommit
            DECLARE
                newUser web.view_users%rowType;
            BEGIN
                newUser := web.create_user('some@email.com', 'aaabbbccc', 'lang');
            END
        $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as I posted this I figured it out... The function does return type web.users, I was trying to assign the return value to web.view_users